# Github push error: can't read "some_heads_tracking": no such variable

Tags: git, github, push

I have the GitHub desktop application installed, and the "Git Shell" on my desktop in Windows.

The folder I want to add to the repository has the `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` files in there.

I went to the folders in File Explorer, right clicked and opened the "Git Commit Tool".

Did Rescan, Staged Changed, Sign Off, Commit. Then when I try to "Push" I get the error:

"can't read 'some_heads_tracking': no such variable

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen that error before as I'm just starting to get deep into git as well but I learned a lot from codeacademy

https://www.codecademy.com/articles/push-to-github <- Has steps to push

I've found sometimes it's better to use the cmd line because you'll get more detailed error messages.

Good luck

Comment: Yea, now I got some more experience with git in the past few days, and realized it's much better to use git from the command line than use a GUI for it.

Comment: yes it is easy enough to just run `git push origin master` off the command line but I want to use the GUI.  I get the same error after a fresh install of Git Bash.  Judging by the crap syntax `"if {!$some_heads_tracking || ![is_tracking_branch $line]} {
   lappend all_heads [string range $line $rh_len end]
  }"` it appears to be an error in a shell script.